# Export Figures with transparent background

Tags: plotting, legending

I have used Mathematica version 13.0.1.0. When I export any Plot in jpg or png format from Mathematica, plot always exported with white background.

How do I remove the background and export a plot with transparent background from Mathematica?

Comment: Background->None option needs to be used